# Is there a way to name the inner mapValues() topic created as part of the count() operator in kafka-streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm, trying to name *all* processors of a simple word count kafka streams application, however, can't figure out how to name the inner topic created due to the `mapValues()` call inside the `count()` method, that's created as result of calling to `stream()`. This is the application code, followed by the topology description (showing only the second sub-topology):

```scala
def createTopology(builder: StreamsBuilder, config: Config): Topology = {
    val consumed = Consumed
      .as(inputTopic)
      .withKeySerde(Serdes.stringSerde)
      .withValueSerde(Serdes.stringSerde)
    val produced = Produced
      .as(outputTopic)
      .withKeySerde(Serdes.stringSerde)
      .withValueSerde(Serdes.longSerde)
    val flatMapValuesProc = Named.as("flatMapValues")
    val groupByProc = Grouped
      .as("groupBy")
      .withKeySerde(Serdes.stringSerde)
      .withValueSerde(Serdes.stringSerde)

    val textLines: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream[String, String](inputTopic)(consumed)
    val wordCounts: KTable[String, Long] = textLines
      .flatMapValues(textLine => textLine.toLowerCase.split("\\W+"), named = flatMapValuesProc)
      .groupBy((_, word) => word)(grouped)
      .count(Named.as("count"))(Materialized.as(storeName))

    wordCounts
      .toStream(Named.as("toStream"))
      .to(outputTopic)(produced)

    builder.build()
  }
```

[image]

Looking at the `count()` method, it seems like it's not possible to name this operation, from the code. Is there another way to name this inner topic?

```scala
  def count(named: Named)(implicit materialized: Materialized[K, Long, ByteArrayKeyValueStore]): KTable[K, Long] = {
    ...
    new KTable(
      javaCountTable.mapValues[Long](
        ((l: java.lang.Long) => Long2long(l)).asValueMapper,
        Materialized.`with`[K, Long, ByteArrayKeyValueStore](tableImpl.keySerde(), Serdes.longSerde)
      )
    )
  }
```

Comment: `mapValues` is stateless; it doesn't create an output topic, `toStream().to` does

Comment: That's right, but it's still the mapValues call that isn't named

Comment: You're welcome to create `new KTable` yourself instead of calling `.count()`. Then you can use [`mapValues(... Named)`](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.html#mapValues(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper,org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Named))

Comment: That would work, but count() is a basic operator, that I was hoping I could use as is, without having names issues

Comment: As you've found in the source code, that Named parameter isn't provided, so there's no other way to "pass it in" from somewhere else, really without maybe resorting to reflection